# uib-popover-template with dynamic url

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use a `uib-popover-template` in a grid and supply an `Id` in the url. Can I create the url dynamically? Something like:

`uib-popover-template="../assets/asset-bulk-upload/edit-bulk-asset/{{asset.AssetId}}"`

This does not seem to work. If I "hard code" it on my angular scope it works fine.

```
<a href="" title="" class="btn btn-primary"
    ng-if="asset.Error"
    uib-popover-template="../assets/asset-bulk-upload/edit-bulk-asset/{{asset.AssetId}}"
    popover-title="{{asset.AssetCode}}"
    popover-trigger="outsideClick"
    popover-placement="auto left"
    tabindex="2"
    ng-click="openPopover();">@Model.FixErrorsLabel</a>
```

This does work (but `Id` is static):

```
   $scope.dynamicPopover = {
     assetEditBulkTemplateUrl: '../assets/asset-bulk-upload/edit-bulk-asset/5'
   };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uib-popover-template` takes an expression, and it evaluates it against underlying `scope` variable. You should rather provide string with and the remaining part can be easily concatenated

```
uib-popover-template="'../assets/asset-bulk-upload/edit-bulk-asset/'+asset.AssetId"
```